# Memory management and S4 class in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-s4

Let suppose I have an S4 class `A` which contains a slot `@S` which is a `data.frame`. The `data.frame` has a column `X`. I want to process such object in C++ using `Rcpp`. Here a toy example of how I did that:

```
SEXP f(S4 A)
{
  DataFrame S = A.slot("S");
  NumericVector X = S["X"];

  // do something with X
}
```

My questions are the following.

- Does `X` is still a reference to the original R data or a deep copy? Considering how Rcpp works is should not be a copy. But how can I be sure?
- This code compiles and works well but the IDE (Rstudio not the compiler) raise a warning: `conversion from 'Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy< Rcppp::S4_Impl<PreserveStorage >::SlotProxy' to 'DataFrame' (aka 'DataFrame_Impl< PreserveStorage >') is ambigous.`What does it mean? Is is serious?

Thanks

Comment: No copies on the way down -- all just `SEXP` internally.  Use memory profiling to convince yourself.  As for the warning, sometimes it helps to disentangle compound statements.

Comment: The best way to convince yourself is to try to modify the first element of `X` and see if it has been modified in the original object.

Comment: FWIW I get no warning when I compile this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I get no warning when compiling. Rstudio give me a warning in the text editor. Rstudio is a very good IDE it always provides good information. This is the first time the compiler is not in accordance with Rstudio.